# Reset a user's password without Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission in ADB2C using MS Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Previously, I was able to reset a user's password by using the following steps:

1. Get an access token with an administrator's credentials and setting the scope to Directory.AccessAsUser.All from [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btenant_id%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)
2. Pass the new password in a passwordProfile object and hit the [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{oid}}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7B%7Boid%7D%7D) using the access token retrieved from the first step.

But now, I cannot find Directory.AccessAsUser.All under Delegated API Permissions.
[image: delegated permissions]

[image]

[image]

How can I change a user's password without it?

Comment: Scroll down to the "Directory" entry and click on the arrow

Comment: @HongOoi there is nothing such as "Directory" in my view. I updated the question with a few more screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

If your application or script needs to update users' passwords, you need to assign the `User administrator` role to your application. The `User administrator` role has a fixed set of permissions you grant to your application.

[See Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga#optional-grant-user-administrator-role)

To add the `User administrator` role, follow these steps:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal and use the Directory + Subscription filter to switch to your Azure AD B2C tenant.
2. Search for and select Azure AD B2C.
3. Under Manage, select Roles and administrators.
4. Select the `User administrator` role.
5. Select Add assignments.
6. In the Select text box, enter the name or the ID of the application you registered earlier, for example, managementapp1. When it appears in the search results, select your application.
7. Select Add. It might take a few minutes to for the permissions to fully propagate.

Comment: I just did that, it's works, without added Directory.AccessAsUser.All.
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the application registration, choose the first option - accounts in this organisational directory. You won’t use this app for B2C user flows, only for your admin AAD account, hence you choose the first option.

Comment: I need to perform ROPC login and for that I'll need to leverage a user flow.

Comment: Use 2 app registrations. One to represent your server (Accounts in this directory), one for AAD B2C user flows (your client app).

Comment: Can I add a client secret and necessary API permissions to the automatically created app registration which says "b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data." ? Will my action break anything?

Comment: Follow my advice exactly. You do not want to touch b2c-extensions-app as it says!
An app registration represents a client. Your client is a Web Server (to make Graph API calls), and a Consumer facing app (to login consumers via User Flows). Use 2 App reg of the respective type to meet the requirement.

Comment: The best option is to use App Reg type: Accounts in this Org, then create a client secret against it. Then assign a directory role to the servicePrincipal (User admin role), then use those creds to do password reset (client_credential flow, rather than ROPC).

Answer (score 0):

Just search "Directory.AccessAsUser.All" for it.

[image]

Comment: I searched for it but there is nothing such as Directory section in my view. Updating the question with another screenshot of what I see.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that is app of Azure B2C. You need to add **application permission** and grant admin consent for your tenant. There is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#code-sample-how-to-programmatically-manage-user-accounts) in offical document, and it is based on client credentials flow.