# How to query MS Graph API in User Context?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to change a user's password using MS Graph API. I was checking earlier questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424978/reset-a-users-password-without-directory-accessasuser-all-permission-in-adb2c-u) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45984323/1307609) where the answer were always similar: register an AAD application, because changing the password requires Delegated
UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All permissions, and you cannot set that in a B2C application as a B2C app supports only offline_access and openid for Delegated.

So the answers were always suggesting creating an AAD app, and using this app I could query the Graph API on behalf of the user. The question is, how to achieve this? If I check the documentation from Microsoft: [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user), it is saying that first you need to get authorization, only then you can proceed to get your access token.
But as part of the authorization process, there is a user consent screen. If I'm calling my ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint to change my password on behalf of my user, how will it work on the server? The client won't be able to consent, if I'm doing these calls on the server, right?

Also, I'm using Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.Auth Nuget packages and it's not clear how to perform these calls on behalf of the user. I was trying to do this:

```
var client = new GraphServiceClient(new SimpleAuthProvider(authToken));
await client.Users[myUserId]
      .ChangePassword(currentPassword, newPassword)
      .Request()
      .PostAsync();
```

Where SimpleAuthProvider is just a dummy IAuthProvider implementation.
Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it:

```
static void ChangePasswordOfAUser()
{
    var myAzureId = "65e328e8-5017-4966-93f0-b651d5261e2c"; // id of B2C user
    var currentPassword = "my_old_pwd";
    var newPassword = "newPassword!";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var passwordTokenRequest = new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            ClientId = clientId, // client ID of AAD app - not the B2C app!
            ClientSecret = clientSecret,
            UserName = $"{myAzureId}@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            Password = currentPassword,
            Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" // you need to have delegate access
        };
        var response = client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(passwordTokenRequest).Result;
        var userAccessToken = response.AccessToken;

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {userAccessToken}");
        var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
        {
            currentPassword = currentPassword,
            newPassword = newPassword
        });
        var changePasswordResponse = client.PostAsync(
            $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{myAzureId}/changePassword",
            new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        .Result;

        changePasswordResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```