# Azure AD B2C reset password options when calling Microsoft Graph from an API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is there any way to reset a B2C user's password from a b2c app granted only application permissions for Microsoft Graph?

We have a scenario where there are non email users in a multi-tenant app and we need to allow admins to reset passwords. To provide user management features we have an app service which uses the .net Microsoft.Graph SDK. It seems the only way to reset a users password is to use [resestPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp), but this cannot be called by an Application.

As far as I can see the only option open to us is to setup a user for this task and store their details in Azure Key vault, then have the app sign in as the user to call the endpoint.

I would really like to avoid this approach if possible and it seems like this must be a common scenario so I am hoping there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> **Note** that: As per the [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp), currently it is not possible to reset password for users with  granting only Application permissions.

Resetting the users password with Application permissions will lead to the below error:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/authentication/passwordMethods/28c10230-6103-485e-b985-444c60001490/resetPassword 
Content-type: application/json
 {
 "newPassword": "xxxx"
  }
```

[image]

**Alternatively**, I created an Azure AD Application and granted below API permissions:

[image]

Grant **User Administrator role** to the Service principal like below:

[image]

Now generate the access token via **Client Credential flow** using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

Using the above generated token, try **resetting the password** using the below query:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "passwordProfile": {
      "password": "xxxx"
  }
}
```

[image]

You can use `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn` parameter based on your requirement.

**References:**

[Azure Reset Password using Graph API by CarlZhao-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/709720/azure-reset-password-using-graph-api)

[Reset a user's password in ADB2C using MS Graph API by kh_Ro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424978/reset-a-users-password-without-directory-accessasuser-all-permission-in-adb2c-u)

Comment: This worked great thank you. I hadn't added the User Principal to the User Administrator Role. Even with that resetPassword endpoint doesn't work but updating the user does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use update user to reset a B2C user's password.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
    "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
  }
}
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions